# Is it possible to find two values for a base?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers, natural-numbers

To find the base p bellow
$$231_p \times 15_p = 4135_p$$

I did,
$$(2p^2 + 3p + 1) \cdot (1p + 5) = 4p^3 + 1p^2 + 3p + 5$$
$$2p^2-12p-13=0$$
$$p = \{\frac{12 + \sqrt{248}}{4}, \frac{12 - \sqrt{248}}{4}\}$$

this looks weird to me, though, because I found two values for a base. So is it possible or did I do something wrong?

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Since there is a digit 5, it means that the base is at least 6

Comment: Ah okay I see @Andrei

Comment: I checked your calculations : they are correct. You should have indeed found an integer. Probably an error in the text of your homework.

Comment: If your problem is $231_p \times 15_p = 41\color{red}{2}5_p$, the equation becomes $2p^2-12p-14=0$ with integer solutions $p=0,p=-1,p=7$, the last one being the only acceptable one.

Comment: @JeanMarie +1: that's a nice catch.